# Users being logged out more often after migration to HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I upgraded a website (venuefinder.com) to responsive design a few weeks ago and at the same time, redirected any HTTP traffic to HTTPS.  Since then, some users (and the site owner) claim they are unexpectedly logged out of the site even though they have the "remember me" checkbox checked.

What might be causing this? From what I can tell the cookie set is permanent, there is no code which calls FormsAuthentication.SignOut()  except for the log out button or if the user is deleted from the database.

Google Analytics confirms the login page is being hit far more often than it was before the code change:

Could this be related to the HTTP > HTTPS migration?

**Login page, page views:**
[image]

Google Analytics confirms the login page is being hit far more often than it was before the code change:

I don't even know where to begin to debug this.

I have set a machine key in web.config in case it was something to do with the cookie becoming invalid but it hasn't helped.

Comment: Start with web.config to confirm no changes were made re `sessionState` and `authentication` timeouts.

Comment: Those sections are identical :/

Comment: check for the application logs if enabled. You can use Application Insights or similar to start tracking if haven't yet:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview#get-started?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5001932

Comment: This isn't an Azure app - it's hosted on bare metal.

Comment: Could it be that the "remember me" checkbox relies on a cookie which was set on the non SSL domain, and the cookie is not there anymore now that the site is hosted on SSL? I would start with the IIS log and try to backtrack what a user did before hitting login page

Comment: Can users still reach the http site if they have bookmarked it or typed it directly? If so a cookie for http and https logins differ. So if you logged in from http and then hit the site from https you would need to log in to that site as well.

Comment: Good point. But I would have expected the hits to login page to die down quick quickly. However 5 weeks on, it's still really high.  It's one of those things which is really hard to fix as you can't easily reproduce it.

Comment: Is this a single server environment or multiple servers/load balancing? I just recently heard about an issue with security signatures being tied to a specific server, so when a connection get rerouted to a different server, the server has to re-validate.

Comment: It's a single server and just in case, I've defined a machine key in the web.config just to make sure that can't change when the app recycles etc.

Comment: @NickG try to login as user in debug mode and see what exception occurs during redirection .

Comment: Any chance there's a hard-coded self-referential link buried somewhere in the code that goes to http? That might induce unexpected redirects/restarts. Just a thought